# How to find ObjectGUID of an Active Directory user (preferable without writing any code)?

Tags: active-directory

I am in quick need of finding objectGUID of an Active Directory user to pass it in the .NET application I have written. The server is Windows 2003.

Is there anything in Active Directory Manager Console for seeing the objectGUID, objectSID, etc?

Regards,

Nirman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't use Windows 2003, but in 2008 R2, in the Active Directory Users and Computers,  select View in the top options, then "Advanced Features".

Select your user > Properties > Attribute Editor. You can find your objectSid or objectGUID and so on.